# Sharepoint 2010 subsite permissions

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, inheritance

I'm new az the SP Designer "business"... 
Which are those **subsites**, where the permissions are **not** automatically **inherited**??

Answer (score 1):

All subsites do by default inherit permissions from their parent.

Someone (or something, code, workflow etc) must break the permission inheritance for a subsite to get unique permissions.

This post describes how to do that in the GUI: http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/break-inheritance-permissions-in-sharepoint-2010-t.html